# Узнать какие checkbox выбраны, js

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Мне нужно узнать какие элементы в checkBoxList выбранные, и передать их id;

```
log = $( ".select_cities :checked" ).val();  
$.post("list?id='.'"+log;
```

Вот таким образом id передается, но проблема в том, что у меня форма динамическая, т.е. я могу еще точно такую же добавить. 
Проблема в том, что если форма `select_cities` одна - все работает, но когда я добавляю еще одну - значение id = `id:undefined`

Почему это происходит? Ведь я ищу по id формы, а id не меняется в зависимости от количества элементов на странице. Скажите что я не так делаю, и как это исправить??

Вот такой код div`a 1-го элемента

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот такой второго

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Видно, что меняется только имя, но я по имени не выбираю, почему тогда не работает ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$("button").on("click", function() {
  var log = $( ".select_cities :checked" ).map(function () {
      return this.value;
    }).get().join(","); 

  console.log(log);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="select_cities">
  <input type="checkbox" value="c1" />
  <input type="checkbox" value="c2" />
  <input type="checkbox" value="c3" />
  <input type="checkbox" value="c4" />
  <input type="checkbox" value="c5" />
  <input type="checkbox" value="c6" />
  <input type="checkbox" value="c7" />
</div>

<div class="select_cities">
  <input type="checkbox" value="d1" />
  <input type="checkbox" value="d2" />
  <input type="checkbox" value="d3" />
  <input type="checkbox" value="d4" />
  <input type="checkbox" value="d5" />
  <input type="checkbox" value="d6" />
  <input type="checkbox" value="d7" />
</div>

<button>click</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо,работает)